# Swift UITableViewCell has overlapping text while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uilabel, overlapping

I am using UITableView and UITableViewCell in Swift and each time I scroll down, the cells overlap additional information on the cell and the data is unreadable. In this code, I am simply using an array of Doubles prin I know this has something to do with reusable cells, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allNumbers.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


        configureCell(cell, number: allNumbers[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }



    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, number: Double) {
        //let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
        //cell.textLabel.text = object.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description


        var doubleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(145, 10, 77, 21))
        var doubleInput = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(230, 10, 77, 21))

        //add all to cell
        cell.self.addSubview(doubleLabel)
        cell.self.addSubview(doubleInput)

        //label text setter
        doubleLabel.text = "Double: "
        doubleInput.text = String(format:"%.1f", number)
    }
```

Comment: Your adding new labels every time a cell is reused. If you want to create labels in code, you should create a subclass, and add the labels in the init method. You should only be populating those labels in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @rdelmar Wouldn't creating a subclass just result in the subclass's init method being called each time if I were to place it in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Place what in cellForRowAtIndexPath? The init method will only be called when a cell is created, not when it's reused. A table view only creates enough cells that can fit on the screen at one time.

Comment: Say my class was called CustomCell and in it's init method I initialized my label and my input. Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I made a new object: var myCustomCell: CustomCell = CustomCell(cell, number: allNumbers[indexPath.row]). Then, wouldn't myCustomCell be called every single time the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called, resulting in the same problem?

Comment: You don't make new cells like that, you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:. It makes a new cell if it needs to , but reuses an old one if there's one available. You should read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS". It explains how to use table views.

Comment: I will definitely look into that. What would be the correct way to do? How would I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath to create a new subclass? I went off of the Master Detail Application template provided and modified their configureCell method.

Comment: You don't use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath to create a new subclass, you misunderstood what I said. You create a subclass by adding a new file just like you create any subclass. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath is used by the table view to provide a cell to display. The only thing different that you do with that method is instead of having "as UITableViewCell" at the end, you would put "as MyCustomCellClass" at the end.